Compute $\int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{3}} \frac{\tan(x)}{1+\tan(x)}\ dx$
I have to calculate
$$\int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{3}} \frac{\tan(x)}{1+\tan(x)}\ dx$$
This is my attempt.
I decide to do it by sostituition, so:
$t=\tan(x) \Longrightarrow x=\arctan(t) \Longrightarrow dx=\frac{dt}{1+t^2}$.
Therefore:
$$\int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{3}} \frac{\tan(x)}{1+\tan(x)}\ dx=\int_1^{\sqrt{3}} \frac{t}{(1+t)(1+t^2)}\ dt$$
Now I use the simple fracts to rewrite the integrand:
$$\frac{t}{(1+t)(1+t^2)}=\frac{A}{1+t}+\frac{Bt+C}{1+t^2}=\frac{A+At^2+Bt+C+Bt^2+Ct}{(1+t)(1+t^2)}=\frac{(A+B)t^2+(B+C)t+A+C}{(1+t)(1+t^2)}$$
To have the equivalence, we need to set the following conditions:
$$\begin{cases}A+B=0 \\ B+C=1 \\ A+C=0\end{cases} \Longrightarrow \begin{cases}A=-1/2 \\ B=1/2 \\ C=1/2\end{cases}$$
So, we have that :
$$\frac{t}{(1+t)(1+t^2)}=\frac{-1}{2(1+t)}+\frac{t+1}{2(1+t^2)}$$
and then:
$$\int_1^{\sqrt{3}} \frac{t}{(1+t)(1+t^2)}\ dt=-\frac{1}{2}\int_{1}^{\sqrt{3}} \frac{1}{1+t}\ dt +\frac{1}{2}\int_{1}^{\sqrt{3}}\frac{1+t}{(1+t^2)}\ dt=$$ $$=-\frac{1}{2}\Bigl[\ln(1+t)\Bigl]^\sqrt{3}_1+\frac{1}{2}\Bigl[\arctan(t)+\frac{1}{2}\ln\left(1+t^2\right)\Bigl]^{\sqrt{3}}_1=[...]$$
Is this correct? Is there a shorter way to do it?

$$\int \frac{\tan x}{1+\tan x} \mathrm dx=\int \mathrm  dx-\int \frac1{1+\tan x}\mathrm  dx=x-\int \frac{\cos x}{\sin x+\cos x}\mathrm  dx$$
To solve the last integral, note that:
$$ \int \frac{\cos x}{\sin x+\cos x}\mathrm  dx=\frac12\int \frac{\sin x+\cos x +\cos x-\sin x}{\sin x+\cos x}\mathrm  dx$$
Edit
As pointed out by Vasili, there'a a faster method:
$$\int \frac{\tan x}{1+\tan x} \mathrm dx=\int \frac{\sin x}{\sin x+\cos x}\mathrm dx=\frac12\int\frac{\sin x+\cos x-\cos x+\sin x}{\sin x+\cos x}\mathrm dx $$

Yes, it's a clever play... I had thought of the first step too but I wouldn't have thought of the second, thank you very much!!

Nice answer!. I think a slightly easier path is to start by multiplying by $\cos x$ both numerator and denominator.

@Vasili that's definitely faster!

$$\begin{align*}
& \int_\tfrac\pi4^\tfrac\pi3 \frac{\tan x}{1+\tan x} \, dx \\
&= \int_0^\tfrac\pi{12} \frac{1+\tan y}2 \, dy & y=x-\frac\pi4 \\
&= \frac\pi{24} - \frac12 \log \left(\cos \frac\pi{12}\right)
\end{align*}$$
